# WSO2 Identity Server migration 5.10 -- 5.11 : Verification for an Updated Mobile Number feature Not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I had an identity server **5.10** installed, and I had to migrate to version **5.11** for several reasons, one of which was to be able to activate the '**mobile number verification for an updated mobile number**' feature since it is not supported by the 5.10 version at a certain update level.

After the migration, I have tried to enable the feature and selected the checkbox '**Enable user mobile number verification on update**', under : Main > Identity Providers > Resident > Account Management Policies > User Claim Update, as described in the documentation.

Unfortunately, it does not work. When I try to perform the update operation on mobile number by invoking the SCIM 2.0 Users endpoint, the verification workflow is not triggered and I get a json response without the "**pendingMobileNumber**" field .

```
curl -v -k --user [username]:[password] -X PATCH -d '{"schemas":[],"Operations":[{"op":[operation],"value":{[attributeName]:[attribute value]}}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/[user ID]
```

In the other hand, I have been able to successfully activate the feature in a separated identity server **5.11** that I have installed for test purposes (without the migration process).

The same steps/configurations were applied for both servers (with and without migration) : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/enable-verification-for-updated-mobile-number/

Is there any specific configurations for migrated platforms in order to activate this feature ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I suspect the issue is not having the newly introduced claims for the feature in your migrated IS tenant. can you check whether there is a local claim named 
Verification Pending Mobile Number (`http://wso2.org/claims/identity/mobileNumber.pendingValue`) in claims list `http://wso2.org/claims` and there is urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:pendingMobileNumber claim under `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User` claims list?

Comment: Or else missing `pendingMobileNumber` attribute definition in `scim2-schema-extension.config` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the following items exist, if not configure as mentioned.

1. Create the local claim `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/mobileNumber.pendingValue` similar to
   [image]
   Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#add-the-custom-claim
2. Create a SCIM claim and map it to the above-created local claim, similar to
   [image]
   Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#map-the-custom-claim
3. Add the following attribute definition to scim2-schema-extension.config file at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/`

```
{
"attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:pendingMobileNumber",
"attributeName":"pendingMobileNumber",
"dataType":"string",
"multiValued":"false",
"description":"Store user's mobile number to be updated as a temporary claim until mobile number verification happens.",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"mutability":"readWrite",
"returned":"default",
"uniqueness":"none",
"subAttributes":"null",
"canonicalValues":[],
"referenceTypes":[]
}
```

and add `pendingMobileNumber` as a sub-attribute of `"attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User",` object at the end of the file

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api

4. Restart the IS server and try out the flow

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have already checked these elements . The local claim  and the scim claim  exist and are correctly mapped . the scim2-schema-extension.config file is also correctly configured .. but the behavior is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: Somehow, It has worked after recreating the scim claim `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:pendingMobileNumber`
using the claim management API . Thanks for the insight .